# How to call a static method of class?

Tags: typescript

I am currently working on an Angular4 Web application and I am trying to write a unit test for a class and pipes that have only public static methods. By now I have not found any solution to do that. Anything that works for components, service etc. does not work here.

Example: Class

```
export class StringExtensions {
    public static firstToLowerCase = ( argument: string ): string => {
        return `${ argument.substr( 0, 1 ).toLowerCase() }${ argument.substr( 1 ) }`;
    }
}
```

Example: not working Unittest

```
import {StringExtensions} from './string-extensions';

describe('StringExtensions', () => {

    let classStringExtensions: StringExtensions;
    const argument: string = 'ArgumenTas';

    beforeEach(() => {
        classStringExtensions = new StringExtensions();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        classStringExtensions = null;
    });

    it('should ...', () => {
        expect(classStringExtensions.firstToLowerCase(argument)).toBe('argumenTas');
    });

});
```

ErrorMessage:

```
ERROR in .../string-extensions.spec.ts (17,38): 
Property 'firstToLowerCase' does not exist on type 'StringExtensions'.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you calling the static method on an instance, you need to call it on the type as static members are accessed at the type level.

```
expect(StringExtensions.firstToLowerCase(argument)).toBe('argumenTas');
```

The current code inside of the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` are also not necessary.

This question is general to typescript and not specific to any framework.

Comment: @JessicaM. - glad to help. Please consider marking it as the answer using the check mark on the left side of the answer.